# Paraview Unstructured Grid Error and Slow Animation

Tags: visualization, vtk, paraview

Since updating Paraview from version 4.2 to 5.0.1 I know get the following error every time I open the .vtu files I have written (or the .pvd which links to the .vtu's).

```
ERROR: In C:\bbd\df0abce0\build\paraview\src\paraview\ParaViewCore\ClientServerCore\Rendering\vtkCompositeRepresentation.cxx, line 380
vtkPVCompositeRepresentation (0000000009BE9DD0): No representation was found with Name: Point Sprite
```

The key point here being "No representation was found with Name: Point Sprite". I do not know why this appears as I never specify that the representation Point Sprite is requred. I do know that version 5.0.1 has dropped the point sprite representation in favour of the new Point Gaussian.

Despite this error the data loads as normal and I can visualise it. Although playing the time sequence (even with the basic Points representation) is now painfully slow and there is a very distinct lag from file to file. Could anyone point out what I might be doing wrong or what I might need to change? Is this something that can be fixed or should I roll back to a previous Paraview version.

**UPDATE**

It might be useful to see the .pvd and .vtu file type I am using:

The .pvd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <VTKFile type="Collection" version="0.1">                                                          
  <Collection>                                                                                      
   <DataSet timestep="001" group="" part="0" file="VTU/REAL/000100_Real_Part.vtu"/>
   ......                                
   </Collection>                                                                                    
  </VTKFile>
```

The .vtu:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type= "UnstructuredGrid"  version= "0.1"  byte_order= "BigEndian">                         
 <UnstructuredGrid>                                                                                 
  <Piece NumberOfPoints="X" NumberOfCells="X">                                                
   <PointData Scalars="Pressure" Vectors="Velocity">                                                
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="A" format="ascii">  
    </DataArray>                                                                                                                                                                      
   </Points>                                                                                        
   <Cells>                                                                                          
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii"> 
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
   </Cells>                                                                                         
  </Piece>                                                                                          
 </UnstructuredGrid>                                                                                
</VTKFile>
```

**UPDATE**

Everyhing works fine with version 4.4.0.

**UPDATE**

Running on Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. Binaries are from paraview.org.

Comment: which OS is this on? Are you using binaries from paraview.org or did you build it yourself? Can you try running with "-dr" command line option? Let's see if something in your settings is causing the issue.

Comment: are you by any chance connecting  a remote server? You'd get similar errors if your remote server was built with OpenGL (legacy) rendering backend, while the client was built with OpenGL2 (new) rendering backend -- which binaries from paraview.org are.